# Map key to value in python directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, key

i have a directory:

```
ca={'currency': ["-RMB"],
 'Country': ['‐China,
  '‐Japan',
  '‐USA',
  '‐UK',
  '‐Mexico'],
 'Languages':["-Chinese","-Japanese","-English","English","Spanish"]}
```

And i only want to print out the key, make it a array:look like:

```
["Currency","Country","Country","Country","Country","Languages","Languages","Languages","Languages","Languages"],
```

I have tried few way, like access each:

`ca.["Country"].replace("Country")`,I know the syntax is wrong but its my logic.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: I can't guess what procedure would create that array from that dictionary. Please explain more.

Comment: its just a main category and sub category but now i only want to print out main category but matches all sub categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to obtain the keys the same number of times as the values:

```
[x for x,y in zip(ca.keys(),ca.values()) for i in y]

['currency', 'Country', 'Country', 'Country', 'Country', 'Country', 'Languages', 'Languages', 'Languages', 'Languages', 'Languages']
```